# Wolves and Sheep! How do I correctly check if two lists are the same in python (same elements in same positions, including nested lists)?

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to code a program that will solve the sheep and wolves problem (also known as prisoners and guards problem, missionaries and cannibals problem, etc.).

**The problem:** Three sheep and three wolves must cross a river using a boat which can carry at most two animals. At no time can you have the wolves outnumber the sheep on either bank of the river. Additionally, you cannot send the boat across the river without carrying at least one wolf or sheep.

**Background on my code so far:** My code is supposed to take different starting numbers of sheep and wolves and return a solution of how many sheep/wolves to move each turn to solve the problem, or return an empty list if the problem is not solvable.

So far, I've created a function that will generate all possible moves (combinations of wolves/sheep to send over to the other bank of the river) regardless of if they are valid or not. I am now working on a function that will iterate through each generated move and determine whether or not the move is valid. The function will return a list containing only the valid moves.

**My problem:** I'm having trouble setting up a condition based on moving only one wolf or sheep. In the starting state of the problem (where all three sheep/wolves are on one bank) there is an option to send either one sheep or one wolf to the other bank. The problem with this move is that it is ultimately unproductive as the only next valid move after this would be to send that sheep or wolf right back (as they would be the only animal on the side with the boat to send back).

A move (or state) is formatted as a list of lists. The first list in this list includes three numbers in the following order: number of sheep, number of wolves, boat indicator (1 if the boat is on that side, 0 if it is not on that side). This list represents the left bank of the river. The second list is the exact same and represents the right bank of the river. For example, the starting condition (three sheep, three wolves, and the boat on the left bank) would look like this:  `[[3,3,1],[0,0,0]]` If you moved two wolves over to the right bank, the state would look like this: `[[3,1,0],[0,2,1]]`.

The unproductive move I described two paragraphs will look like one of the following states: `[[1,0,1],[2,3,0]]`, `[[0,1,1],[3,2,0]]`, `[[2,3,0],[1,0,1]]`, `[[3,2,0],[0,1,1]]`. Condition 4 and 5 below (c4, c5) are how I'm trying to see if the possible state matches this criterial and should be eliminated, however it's not working for me. When I start with an initial state of three wolves, three sheep, and the boat on the left hand bank, I produce the following possible states:

```
[[[2, 3, 0], [1, 0, 1]], 
[[1, 3, 0], [2, 0, 1]], 
[[3, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1]], 
[[3, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]], 
[[2, 2, 0], [1, 1, 1]]]
```

The first and third states are invalid/unproductive because the next move in the problem would require sending that wolf/sheep back in the boat returning the problem to the starting state. However, when I run my code, the function I created returns the following states as valid:

```
[[[3, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1]], 
[[3, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]], 
[[2, 2, 0], [1, 1, 1]]]
```

The first state in this list should be an invalid state. It shows that only one wolf was on the boat traveling from the left bank to the right bank. The only move that can be taken is for that wolf to go back on the boat and return to the left bank thus returning to the starting state.

**I need help understanding why my conditions (specifically conditions four and five) are not working correctly and why it's including states that I'm trying to define as invalid. I'm not sure if I'm missing something with list comprehension and comparison in Python but I haven't yet been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.**

The function I'm using to remove invalid states/identify valid states is below. Condition 4/5 is where I'm having trouble.

```
    def eliminate_states(self, possible_state_list, official_state_list):
        valid_states = []
        for state in possible_state_list:
            # Condition 1: potential move cannot be in states list
            c1 = state not in official_state_list
            # Condition 2/3: wolves cannot outnumber sheep on LEFT/RIGHT side
            c2 = (state[0][1]<=state[0][0] and state[0][0] > 0) or (state[0][1]>state[0][0] and state[0][0] == 0)
            c3 = (state[1][1]<=state[1][0] and state[1][0] > 0) or (state[1][1]>state[1][0] and state[1][0] == 0)
            # Condition 4/5: Don't sent single sheep/wolf to an empty side (results in unproductive state)
            c4 = not (state[0][0]==1 and state[0][1]==0 and state[0][2]==1) or (state[0][0]==0 and state[0][1]==1 and state[0][2]==1) 
            c5 = not (state[1][0]==1 and state[1][1]==0 and state[1][2]==1) or (state[1][0]==0 and state[1][1]==1 and state[1][2]==1)

            condition_list = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]
            if all(condition_list) == True:
                valid_states.append(state)

        return valid_states
```

I've reviewed the conditions I've specified in my formula to ensure they match the list positions of the sheep, wolf, and boat counts. I had previously tried checking for equality against the bad condition (e.g. check if the first list in the state matched [1,0,1] or [0,1,1]) but this didn't eliminate any of the states that matched the criterial. I had to switch to referencing list indexes in order to partially solve the problem, but as you can see I'm still not getting rid of all the states that I want to in order to correctly solve this problem.

Comment: Your `c4` and `c5` are in the form `not x or y`. That's equivalent to `(not x) or y` - it's not the same as `not (x or y)`. Did you maybe mean to do `not (x or y)` instead?